# PHP - Fetching data problem, taking too long to be fetched

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, I'm having a problem fetching my data, it takes so long, literally takes 10 seconds for the data to be fetched into the grid, anyone solved this problem? please advised, thank you!

> > See code below

```
$stVal = $_GET['search'];
$stLimit = $_GET['limit'];
$sql = "";
if($_GET['gdate']==''){
    $gridDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today.'-1 months'));
    $gridfDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($today.'-1 months'));
}else{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['gdate']));
    $gridDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'-1 months'));
    $gridfDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date.'-1 months'));
}
```

> > On this for loop, when I remove the sql statement and put it outside, then the table is shown immidiately, but **IT IS NOT FETCHED CORRECTLY**

```
for($x=0;$x<18;$x++){
        $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($gridDate.'+'.$x.' months'));
        $thisDate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($gridfDate.'+'.$x.' months'));
        $mheader[$x] = date('Y', strtotime($gridDate.'+'.$x.' months'));
        $dheader[$x] = date('M', strtotime($gridDate.'+'.$x.' months'));
        $date = $thisDate AND $thisDate2;

        //See code below for this break line of codes

       $sql .=",(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(tc.`name`) = 0 THEN '<td data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\"></td>' WHEN DATE_FORMAT(min(pd.`duedate`), '%Y-%m') <= DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(max(pd.`duedate`), '%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%Y-%m') THEN '<td class=\"paid\" data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\">Paid Month</td>' ELSE CONCAT('<td data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\" class=\"', CASE WHEN min(p.`duedate`) < '$dateposted' THEN 'occ' WHEN str_to_date(t.`due_date`, '%M %d,%Y') < '$dateposted' AND t.`months` = 0 THEN 'fins' ELSE 'ten' END,'\">', tc.`name`,' #', tc.`transID`,'</td>') END AS gdisp FROM `transaction_con` tc LEFT JOIN `transaction` t ON t.`id` = tc.`transID` LEFT JOIN (select sum(pde.amount) as total, pde.net, pde.pay_type, pde.duedate, pde.transID, pde.item, pt.status from payments_depot pde left join payment_type pt on pt.id = pde.pay_type where pde.`item` = 'House Rate' AND pt.status between 1 and 2 group by pde.paymentid HAVING total = net) pd ON t.`id` = pd.`transID` LEFT JOIN payment_type pt ON pt.`id` = pd.`pay_type` LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.transID = t.id WHERE tc.`apartmentID` = a.`id` AND DATE_FORMAT(tc.`date`, '%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%m-%Y')) AS '$thisDate'";


}
$gData = $gen->gridData($sql,$stVal,$stLimit);
$tableID = 'gridTable';
$merge = 'th,td';

echo json_encode(array(
    'datenow' => date('M', strtotime($dateposted)),
    'tableID' => $tableID,
    'merge' => $merge,
    'dates' => $thisDate,
    'mheader' => $mheader,
    'dheader' => $dheader,
    'date' => $date,
    'gridData' => $gData
));
```

> > SQL Statement code break lines
> >
> > **ALSO** this code, I think is the occurrence of the problem, when I removed this sql code and bring outside the for loop then the data is not fetched correctly, but the table is shown immediately.

```
     (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(tc.`name`) = 0 THEN '<td data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\"></td>' 
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(min(pd.`duedate`), '%Y-%m') <= DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(max(pd.`duedate`), '%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%Y-%m') THEN 

     '<td class=\"paid\" data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\">Paid Month</td>' 

     ELSE CONCAT('<td data-attribute=\"".$thisDate2."\" class=\"', CASE WHEN min(p.`duedate`) < '$dateposted' THEN 'occ' WHEN str_to_date(t.`due_date`, '%M %d,%Y') < '$dateposted' AND t.`months` = 0 THEN 'fins' ELSE 'ten' END,'\">', tc.`name`,' #', tc.`transID`,'</td>') 

     END AS gdisp FROM `transaction_con` tc LEFT JOIN `transaction` t ON t.`id` = tc.`transID` LEFT JOIN (select sum(pde.amount) as total, pde.net, pde.pay_type, pde.duedate, pde.transID, pde.item, pt.status from payments_depot pde left join payment_type pt on pt.id = pde.pay_type where pde.`item` = 'House Rate' 

        AND pt.status between 1 and 2 group by pde.paymentid HAVING total = net) pd ON t.`id` = pd.`transID` 

     LEFT JOIN payment_type pt ON pt.`id` = pd.`pay_type` LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.transID = t.id 

         WHERE tc.`apartmentID` = a.`id` AND DATE_FORMAT(tc.`date`, '%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT('$thisDate', '%m-%Y')) AS '$thisDate'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling all data from a certain month for 18 months, with 18 different queries. I would suggest getting all data from the 18 month period, and then parsing it per month after fetching the data.
This way you are not asking the database to look up the same data 18 times.

Keep your SQL outside of the for loop, and just call the data based on start and enddate of the 18 month window.

EDIT:
I wrote some code on how I would tackle your problem. I'm staying away from the horror that is the sql query. I can't even begin to understand how and why it is what it is.

```
//Write a query that calls for all 18 months of data.
$sql = "SELECT Data for all 18 months";

//Call your Database
$sqlData = queryDatabase($sql, $stVal, $stLimit);

//Parse the Data into 18 seperate months
$gData = ParseData($sqlData);

$tableID = 'gridTable';
$merge = 'th,td';

echo json_encode(array(
    'datenow' => date('M', strtotime($dateposted)),
    'tableID' => $tableID,
    'merge' => $merge,
    'dates' => $thisDate,
    'mheader' => $mheader,
    'dheader' => $dheader,
    'date' => $date,
    'gridData' => $gData
));

//This function slices your sql data into pieces divided by month.
function ParseData($sqlData){
  $dataInMonths = [];
  //This depends on how you select your data from the DB, I'm going to use assoc 
  //arrays right now.
  $i = -1;
  foreach($sqlData as $dataRow){
    $currentDate = $dataRow['date'];
    $currentTime = strtotime($currentDate);
    $currentMonth = date("F-Y", $currentTime);

    if($currentMonth != $previousMonth){
      $i++;
      $dataInMonths[$i] = [];
    }
    $dataInMonths[$i][] = $dataRow;

    $previousMonth = $currentMonth;
  }

  //Now your data is an array of 18 items, each with a month of their own data. 
  //You can now continue to parse it to fit within your grid.

  return $dataInMonths;
}
```

Comment: Good day sir! what is the structure of the code if I'll remove the for loop? please give me a source code for the preference? thank you

Comment: Added an edit to the original. Since I don't have your full codebase I added some dummy code where the code calls for inputs from somewhere else in the program.

Comment: Hello there! where should I put the function`ParseData` in my codes ?

Comment: I also wonder, where should I put my variables inside the for loop before of my original codes? please send me more advice sir! thank you very much!

Comment: The function can go anywhere within the script that is currently being executed.